# Linking 'libstdc++' library is broken in embedded linux

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling

I have been working on a project which will be loaded on an embedded system, has not enough memory/disk space to install a C++ compiler and compile the code, natively.

So, I need to “cross-compile” the code on my development (Host) machine to be used on the target machine (Embedded Linux).

The happening problem related to using strings and iostreams which are a feature of the C++ standard template library (STL). However, because memory is so critical in an embedded system, the standard template library (libstdc++), can not be available on target side.

I need to statistically link the standard libraries on host machine, rather than dynamically link on target side. So, in my Makefile I need to have a slightly complex modification in both compiling and linking steps in order to build my project.

I have used some parameters such as -nodefaultlibs, -static-libstdc++, and -lstdc++ in the linking step and also added -nostdinc++ to the compiler flags. Still, there exist the problem on target side; " can not load library libstdc++.so.6 "

Most of these settings I have tried did not work. Is there any solution?

Comment: I take it you have also cross compiled libstdc++ for your target architecture also before trying to statically link it?

Comment: Actually, I am planning to cross-compile the code in the host machine without cross-compiling any standard c++ libraries, (like libstdc++ library), for target architecture. In host machine, I am trying to link statistically c++ standard libraries which are needed at the run time on target side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lstdc++` overrides `-static-libstdc++`, try linking with just `-static-libstdc++`.

See this for example:

```
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -static-libstdc++ -lstdc++
$ ldd foo
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0056b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x007ae000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x005dd000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002bc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0095e000)
```

libstdc++ is linked dynamically!

```
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -static-libstdc++
$ ldd foo
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0097b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x001f9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0037f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00199000)
```

now it is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive explanation. My original idea was to avoid installing standard c++ libraries such as libstdc++ on the target side, by linking them statically in host machine (because of the limitation in embedded linux on target side). Your answer is absolutely correct.